# Why isn't the convergence rate 1 in ordinary differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, convergence-divergence

For $${d y\over d t} = b -ay,$$ the equilibrium solution is $$y = {b\over a}$$ and the general solution is $$y = {b\over a} + k e^{-at} (k = \pm e^{c}).$$

I was asked to describe how the solutions change when a varies. One part of the answer to it is that the convergence rate is $a$ here and I'm confused about that. After looking up wikipedia about the concept of convergence rate, I learnt that  $$\lim_{k\to \infty} \frac{|x_{k+1}-L|}{|x_k-L|} = \mu$$ and $\mu$ here is the convergence rate. In this case, I thought $x_k+1$ here is ${b\over a} + k e^{-at}$ and $x_k$ here is ${b\over a} + k e^{-at_0}$, L is ${b\over a}$. $\infty$ is replaced with $t_0$ and $k$ is replaced with t. In this way, the limit seems turn out to be 1?

Comment: The convergence rate for functions $y$ such that $y(t)\to y_\infty$ when $t\to\infty$ most probably refers to the number $$r=-\lim_{t\to\infty}t^{-1}\log|y(t)-y_\infty|.$$ In your situation, indeed $r=a$, trivially.

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot!